# how to make $get_db = &JFactory::getDBO(); work in scripts outside joomla 2.5 framework?

Tags: joomla2.5

for joomla 1.5 i used following code lines to get a database object, but whats equivalent code for joomla 2.5? i used many codes but all seems to not working, including found on stackoverflow itself... all i want to call a php script by Ajax to update a drop-down through DB... and im getting the error 500: internal server error

```
// joomla 1.5 code
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] );

require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'joomla' . DS . 'factory.php' );
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');

$get_db  = &JFactory::getDBO();
```

my script file which im calling by ajax has the following code... its still responding internal server error, dont knwo whats wrong with the includes oor constants, if i remove all lines except the last, this works fine and 'hi' is returned by ajax call... im using joomla 2.5.7, any hint ???

```
  //joomla 2.5 script NOT WORKING
  define( '_JEXEC'  1 );
  define( '_VALID_MOS'  1 );
  define( 'JPATH_BASE'  realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
  define( 'DS'  DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
  require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
  require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
  echo JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php';
  $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
  $mainframe->initialise();
  echo $mainframe->getCfg('sitename');
  $db =& JFactory::getDBO(); 

  echo "hi";
```

Comment: working on localhost XAMPP 3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I am using to access Joomlas database from shell-scripts:

```
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) {
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
    require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/framework.php';

// Mark afterLoad in the profiler.
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterLoad') : null;

// Instantiate the application.
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

// Initialise the application.
$app->initialise();

$dbo = JFactory::getDBO();
```

Comment: Thanks @Mbass but this code is throwing errors as path to include (require_once ) is incorrect... :-(

Comment: Sry, forgot to mention, but the script neefs to be placed in the root of your joomla/-nstallation (where index.php resides)